# Recover the overwritten file from google cache

Tags: php, html

I have overwritten my file( a webdocument with extention .php) with the old one, I tried to access the cached version from google and I found the one i.e,http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://minnesotataxiandcarservice.com/testimonials.php&strip=0 but I am looking for a way to recover it, when I tried to view its source code all I can see is the html scrips only as the php part is not visible. Now I am looking for a way to retrive a whole document with original contents including the php coding. If there is any way to do so please mention it.

Comment: AFAIK, this is not possible. There is an option for `folders` in Windows OS to `Restore Previous Versions`, but it won't help in your case.

Comment: You can't. The PHP code is server-side and is not visible from the outside. What the users and Google sees is the HTML-output of your script.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

Next time, you should be using a **[version control system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control)**, like **[Git](http://git-scm.com/)**

Comment: @asifrc: Such an easy tool to use, for such a powerful effect is has on your workflow and peace of mind.